# Not getting token

Tags: ios, objective-c, token

I have enabled app id for push notification and done all the process required for push notification but my problem is when i click on Allow button it gives me token but click on Don't allow it didn't give me token. I didn't find the solution on it getting helpless. Please help me to solve my problem.

Comment: If the user does not allow you to send him/her push notification you will not get a token.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior.  When the user clicks "Don't Allow", a token is not generated.  If you need to find the current status of notification settings, you can use `UNUserNotificationCenter.getNotificationSettings` which returns a `UNNotificationSettings` in it's completion handler.  You can then check the `authorizationStatus` on the settings object.  The status will either be `authorized` if the user has clicked Allow, `denied` if the user clicked Don't Allow, and `notDetermined` if the request hasn't been answered.

Comment: thank you chris. but i want to do some action depends on device token so its executable if user click dont alow. so any kind of solution you have? i want some unique id for device.

Comment: Hi @DhanrajKawade, if you're just looking to identify device, then you don't need notification tokens.  You can use the `identifierForVendor` method on UIDevice.  See here in the docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor